# Xamarin.Forms Binding the visibility of a cell in ListView to field in another cell

Tags: c#, xaml, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I have a list of questions that can include subquestions, that should display depending on the answer provided. I can display the complete list of questions without issue, however this also displays the optional questions; what I need to do is be able to hide and show these as the answers change.

My ViewModel contains a `ObservableCollection<AnsweredQuestion>` property forming the source of the questions. This has been flattened to ease the display, but a nested version is available is required.

AnsweredQuestion:

```
public class AnsweredQuestion
{
    public List<PossibleAnswer> PossibleAnswers;
    public bool CommentsAllowed { get; set; }
    public string Comments { get; set; }
    public string Hint { get; set; }
    public int Order { get; set; }
    public bool Required { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

PossibleAnswer:

```
public class PossibleAnswer
{
    public string Value { get; set; }

    // These questions should be displayed if the answer matches Value above
    public List<AnsweredQuestion> Questions { get; set; }

    // Reference to the parent question
    public AnsweredQuestion Question { get; set; }
    public bool IsVisible { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => this.Value;
}
```

The list binds as normal here:

```
<StackLayout>
    <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="True" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}"/>
    <ListView x:Name="MyListView"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Survey.AnsweredQuestions}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource QuestionDataTemplateSelectorService}"
              HasUnevenRows="True">
    </ListView
</StackLayout>
```

`QuestionDataTemplateSelectorService` simply returns a custom cell-based template depending on the question type. These are like the following, and work correctly:

```
<questions:QuestionViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:questions="clr-namespace:Athena.Mobile.Views.Questions;assembly=Athena.Mobile"
             x:Class="Athena.Mobile.Views.Questions.TextQuestionViewCell"
          BindingContext="{Binding .}">
    <ViewCell.View>
        <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start">
            <Label FontAttributes="Bold" Text="{Binding Text}" />
            <Label FontAttributes="Italic" TextColor="Gray" Text="{Binding Hint}" IsVisible="{Binding HasHint}"  />
            <Entry Text="{Binding Value}"/>

            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" IsVisible="{Binding CommentsAllowed}">
                <Label Text="Comments?" TextColor="Gray" FontAttributes="Italic"/>
                <Entry Text="{Binding Comments}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ViewCell.View>
</questions:QuestionViewCell>
```

How would I go about displaying or hiding question cells, based on the result (`Value`) of the parent question, and the condition defined for it (`PossibleAnswer`)?

I have attempted to bind to the condition, or update the IsVisible property when the Value property sets, but this doesn't seem to push through an update.

Comment: Are you raising the INotifyPropertyChanged event? Right now I can't see the implementation of `HasHint` which seems to control the visibility.

Comment: @FraukeNonnenmacher The ViewModel that hosts the collection implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`, I have also attempted implementing it on the `AnsweredQuestion` model, and recalculating visibility of the fields whenever answer value changes. `HasHint` is irrelevant to the situation, but I haven't had luck with that yet